# Does statistical self-similarity preserve covariance?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion, covariance

Suppose that $X(t)$ is an $\alpha$-fractal Brownian motion.

We know that such a process has the following self-similarity property:

$$X(t) \sim \frac{1}{|a|^{\alpha}} X(at)$$

Where $\sim$ denotes having the same probability distribution.

What I want to understand is whether or not this $\sim$ preserves covariance. For example, does this mean that for any random process $Y(t)$:

$$E[X(t)Y(t)] = E[\frac{1}{|a|^{\alpha}} X(at) Y(t)]$$

The answer isn't clear to me because I'm unsure if the self-similarity means they share all properties including covariance etc, or if they just share the same distribution at time $t$ (ie. Both are $N(0,\sigma^2 t^{2\alpha})$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to know that the pair $(X(t),Y(t))$ has the same distributions as the pair $(|a|^{-\alpha}X(at),Y(t))$. Your expectation identity will then follow because the expectation is determined by the joint distribution.

Comment: Yes I understand that, what I'm asking is whether statistical self similarity of fractal Brownian motion applies to marginal distributions only (in which case its not true), or to all joint distributions (in which case it is).

Comment: Statistical self-similarity of $X(t))_{t\ge 0}$, for example, means that the re-scaled process $(a^{-\alpha}X(at))_{t\ge 0}$ has the same finite-dimensional distributions as $(X(t))_{t\ge 0}$. It is not just one-dimensional marginals at issue.

Comment: Are you sure? When I tried comparing $E(X(t)X(s))$ and $E(a^{-\alpha}X(at)X(s))$ using the covariance formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) I couldn't make them equal. This seems to suggest to me their joint distributions are not equal? Or am I missing something.

Comment: Self-similarity of $X$ would imply that $(X(t), X(s))$ had the same distribution as $(a^{-\alpha}X(at),a^{-\alpha}X(as))$, and in turn that $E[a^{-\alpha}X(at)\cdot a^{-\alpha}X(as)]=a^{-2\alpha}E[X(at)X(as)]$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks!